# MySQL Multiple Where Clauses Using One Table

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a table like this:

```
user_id, name, second_name
```

Sample data:

```
1, "fred", "smith"
2, "john", "smith"
3, "karl", "johnson"
```

I want to find all the people that have a name of say "fred". Then I want to find all the people that have the same second name as "Fred". I would like to do this in one query if possible. A query simialar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name=:first_name OR second_name=:result_from_first_row
```

The output of this sample query would be:

```
1, "fred", "smith"
2, "john", "smith"
```

Comment: It needs to be optional and secondly I don't know what the 'second name' is until the query gets Fred.

Comment: I misread, sorry. Then I don't know the answer, hope someone does. What do you expect to get if there's two or more "fred"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM people WHERE second_name IN (SELECT second_name FROM people WHERE name=:first_name)

Comment: That gave me an error but this seemed to work:
SELECT * FROM people WHERE second_name=(SELECT second_name FROM people WHERE name='fred')

Comment: However I don't believe that's optional.

Comment: please try it again, i used "IS IN" instead of a simple "IN" accidentally